# Can we copy UVediting colors of an object and paste it into our Layout object

Tags: materials, uv, uv-image-editor, color

I am modeling a house and using UV editing now but when I click on Layout the colors are gone

I want the same colors for my Layouts panel so will I have to make individual materials and assign each color to respective object or there is an easy way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get meshes shaded in Solid view is to assign them materials and, in the material tab (on the right), scroll down until you see a property called "Display Color" (or something). This is the color you will see in Solid view and it is also the color your UV's will export with. You must "assign" the material to the faces you want to be that color.